# How to count the number of characters in a text field iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to count the number of characters when User want to validate his password :

I came out so far with this code, but seems doesn't work

```
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

 if (Password!.count < 6)
        {
/// Not acceptable
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about

```
if password.text?.characters.count < 6 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for swift 1? -- "String does not have a member named characters"

Comment: @Mushroomcloud I cannot believe that there's still someone using Swift 1! I really suggest you to update to a more recent version if possible. In Swift 1 probably something like `if let text = password.text where count(text) < 6 { ... }` could work

Comment: Well...I am still using it because there are some small changes for a previous app that need to be done... It will probably take too much time to update the whole app to swift 3 I assume :8 Thank you anyway!

Comment: In the newest version of Swift, "characters" has been deprecated. "password.text.count"

Answer (score 1):

for swift 5, I used this method and it is working fine

```
if password.text.count > 6 {
  //add scenario for this case here
}
```